# How to reverse quantile color palette with CARTO VL

Tags: carto, carto-vl

Using [CARTO VL](https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/) (which is awesome by the way), I have made the following groundwater harvest potential map that is [styled using 10 quantiles](https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/examples/#example-style-by-category).

[image]

Although the "temps" palette works well, is it possible to reverse the colors? I read a thread on GitHub that mentioned using "inverse" like this:

```
color: ramp(globalQuantiles($sa_m3_km2, 10), inverse(temps))
```

But this have never worked for me. Is inverting a quantile palette possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by using the `reverse` expression. Using the code from your example, it would be:

`color: ramp(globalQuantiles($sa_m3_km2, 10), reverse(temps))`

You can find more about this expression in our documentation: https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/reference/#cartoexpressionsreverse

And an example from the reference using the JavaScript API:

```js
const s = carto.expressions;
const viz = new carto.Viz({
  color: s.ramp(s.prop('type'), s.reverse(s.palettes.PRISM));
});
```